# creating and index counting rows by criteria based on previous rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, survey

I am attempting to calculate an index by a grouping construct that must refer to previous rows in a travel survey dataset.  I cannot figure out a proper construct of query to obtain what I am after and would like help from the community.  My travel dataset is in the form below except the TRIPNUM column, and I would like to get the TRIPNUM Column to be like this, or if it is easier like TRIPNUM2:

```
UniqueID,       PersonID,   PlaceType,  PlaceTpyeInt, TravelMode, TRIPNUM, TRIPNUM2 
6001,           600,        Home,       0,            None,       0,       0
6002,           600,        Store,      4,            Car,        1,       1
6003,           600,        Home,       0,            Car,        0,       1
6004,           600,        Store,      4,            Car,        2,       2
6005,           600,        Store,      4,            Car,        2,       2
6006,           600,        Home,       0,            Car,        0,       2
6011,           601,        Home,       0,            None,       0,       0
6012,           601,        Store,      4,            Car,        1,       1
```

...etc.

What I am having trouble with is how to create the criteria necessary to:

1. Count trips as separate instances of the survey respondent leaving and returning home
2. Count multi-stop trips as the same trip
3. Reset the TRIPNUM when changing to the next survey respondent (i.e. PersonID)

Is it necessary to write a iterative function to do this, or is there a way to refer to the previous row, check to see if it is the same PersonID, and then assign it a value based on the previous row's TRIPNUM?

UPDATE:  I have tried implementing this code construct but am not sure this is the correct looping construct to loop over rows by unique personid

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tripcounter(int) RETURNS TABLE AS
$BODY$
DECLARE 
temptrip int;
uniqueid int;
personid int;
tripcount int;

BEGIN
FOREACH personid in $1
temptrip = 0
select uniqueid, perid, ptype, from $1
FOREACH uniqueid
CASE WHEN ptye = 1 
        THEN    tripcount = 0
            temptrip = temptrip + 1
      ptype <> 1
        THEN
            tripcount = temptrip


END LOOP;
END;
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

    ERROR:  syntax error at or near "tripcount"
LINE 1: ...R REPLACE FUNCTION tripcounter(int) RETURNS TABLE tripcount(..
```

Comment: So where is your code? Could you paste it in?

Comment: I don't have any yet.  I have been searching everywhere for a function that can refer to specific rows and don't know how to approach the problem.  Do I need to write a function for this?

Comment: So far, I have SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE placetypeint <> 0, but it doesn't separate based on chronological trip order

Comment: How do you determine "*chronological trip order*" based on the information you provided?

Comment: Can you explain in plain words the logic behind the values that you expect in `tripnum2`?

Comment: I just want to separate trips into round trip journeys from home.  TRIPNUM would be preferred, but I could think I could get away with tripnum2 by then filtering out placetypeint = 0.  I was just thinking from my excel days that somehow it might be easier to refer to the row directly above the one in question, whereas tripnum2 would have to refer to the value 2 rows above to advance the trip counter from tripnum to tripnum + 1.

Comment: so every trip starts with a 4 and ends with a 0 ?

Comment: Yes, or some other integer not equal to 0.

Answer (score 1):

If every trip begins and ends with PlaceType=Home, and assuming your Unique ID's proceed in chronological order, then it seems easy to do using a windowed analytic SQL function such as row_number and a modulo function (denoted by % below).

Use the following as a sketch for how to identify your trip starting and ending points; depending on the indexing (whether it starts at 0 or 1) you may need to flip the trip_start logic.

Once you have the logic to identify starting and ending points, it shouldn't be too hard to create a master table of trip starting points where you define the trip numbers partitioned by person, join it to the corresponding trip ending points so each record is one trip with both starting point and ending point defined in the record, and then join to the original table one last time on uniqueID > startingPoint and uniqueID <= endingPoint to grab all of the stops in the trip,

select *, case when row_number % 2 = 0 then 'trip start' else 'trip end' end as trip_start

from

Select *, row_number over (partition by personID) from Your_Table
where PlaceType = 'Home'